# Mostrar información de dos periodos en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

en esta ocasión necesito traer información de una tabla (vista) que uso para generar los boletines de calificaciones de un colegio, el cual cuenta con 3 periodos de notas.

Lo del primer periodo no hay inconvenientes, el problema se presenta para el segundo y tercer periodo, ya que para el segundo periodo deber mostrar también la nota definitiva del primer periodo, y para el tercer periodo se debe mostrar la nota final del primer y segundo periodo.
Esta es la vista, de donde obtengo la información

[image: Información de los campos de vista]

Y este es el boletín del primer periodo, el cual se debe complementar en segundo y tercer periodo.

[image: Boletín primer período]

Información de la vista "BoletinCompleto", con lo cual se llena el respectivo boletín.

[image: Campos de la vista "Boletincompleto"]

La pregunta es como hago para que al selección la información del segundo período, también me traiga la nota final del primer período, para ir llenando el respectivo boletín.

Se que realizando la tarea del segundo periodo seria lo mismo para llenar el tercer periodo.

Espero me puedan dar ideas he pensado realizarlo en un procedimiento almacenado, para de esta manera poderlo llamar desde el Dataset Tipado en C# desde VS Community 2019, la base de datos que manejo es MySql.
Esta es la consulta SQL, que tengo en el DataSet tipado para seleccionar la información para llenar el boletín del primer período.

```
SELECT        Alumno, BoDetAreaId, BoDetId, BoDetLogros, BoDetMateId, BoDetNotaFinal, BoDetOrdenArea, BoDetPeriId, BoleAnnoLectivo, BoleDoceDocumento, BoleGradId, BoleId, BoleObservaAluId, BoleDirectorId, DiCNombreComp, 
                     Docente, Documento, GradDetalle, Intensidad, Materia, ObAluObservaciones, Período, Área
FROM            boletincompleto
WHERE        (BoleAnnoLectivo = @RepParamAnno) AND (BoleGradId = @RepParamGrado) AND (BoDetPeriId = @RepParamPeriodo) AND (Documento = @RepParamDocuAlumno)
ORDER BY Documento, BoDetOrdenArea, BoDetMateId
```

Para el segundo periodo necesito traer la misma información del primer período, solo que con la información del segundo período y la nota final del primer período.

De esta manera lleno la tabla (vista), por medio del siguiente código SQL.

```
-- VISTA BoletinCompleto vista
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS BoletinCompleto;
CREATE VIEW BoletinCompleto AS
SELECT BolEnca.BoleId, BolEnca.BoleAnnoLectivo, BolDeta.BoDetId, 
BolEnca.BoleAlumDocumento AS Documento, concat_ws(' ', Alum.AlumApellido1, 
Alum.AlumApellido2, Alum.AlumNombre1, Alum.AlumNombre2 ) As "Alumno", 
BolDeta.BoDetPeriId, Peri.PeriDetalle AS Período, BolEnca.BoleGradId, 
Grad.GradDetalle, BolEnca.BoleDoceDocumento, concat_ws(' ', 
Docent.DoceApellidos, Docent.DoceNombres) AS Docente, 
BolEnca.BoleObservaAluId, 
ObsAlum.ObAluObservaciones, BolEnca.BoleDirectorId, DireCol.DiCNombreComp, 
BolDeta.BoDetAreaId, BolDeta.BoDetOrdenArea, Area.AreaDetalle AS Área, 
BolDeta.BoDetMateId, Mate.MateDetalle AS Materia, 
BolDeta.BoDetIntensidad AS Intensidad, BolDeta.BoDetLogros, 
BolDeta.BoDetNotaFinal
FROM boletindetalle As BolDeta
INNER JOIN boletinenca AS BolEnca ON BolDeta.BoDetBoDetId=BolEnca.BoleId
INNER JOIN periodos AS Peri ON BolDeta.BoDetPeriId=Peri.PeriId
INNER JOIN areas AS Area ON BolDeta.BoDetAreaId=Area.AreaId
INNER JOIN materias AS Mate ON BolDeta.BoDetMateId=Mate.MateId
INNER JOIN alumnos AS Alum ON BolEnca.BoleAlumDocumento=Alum.AlumDocumento
INNER JOIN grados AS Grad ON BoleGradId=Grad.GradId
INNER JOIN docentes As Docent ON 
     BolEnca.BoleDoceDocumento=Docent.DoceDocumento
INNER JOIN directorcol As DireCol ON BolEnca.BoleDirectorId=DireCol.DiCId
INNER JOIN observacalumnos AS ObsAlum ON 
     BolEnca.BoleObservaAluId=ObsAlum.ObAluId;
```

De antemano muchas gracias a las personas que me puedan colaborar dando ideas para esta solución.

Comment: Falta la consulta SQL.

Comment: Listo Sal, ya lo agregue, la consulta que utilizo para el primer periodo, gracias.

Comment: Sugiero que añadas la consulta SQL con la que formas la vista `BoletinCompleto`, pues me parece que la mejor solución puede estar en modificar dicha vista, y no en modificar el query que tira de ella.

Comment: es que en la tabla (vista) agrego todas las notas de las materias, como se observa en la tercer imagen.

Comment: Listo jachguate, ya cargue el código SQL, con el cual lleno la vista "BoletinCompleto".

Comment: Viendo el código de la vista, lamentablemente no me queda clara la estructura (debido a que los campos no están calificados en la vista). Sugiero que adaptes el SQL para que tenga campos calificados, o que incluyas el modelo de datos.

Comment: – jachguate, a que se refiere con **los campos no están calificados en la vista**, gracias

Comment: Por ejemplo, el campo `BoDetPeriId`, no sé de que tabla viene (puedo asumirlo y equivocarme, por eso nunca lo asumo). Sería mucho más claro si el select incluyera un alias o el nombre de la tabla, por ejemplo: `boletinenca.BoDetPeriId`. Utiliza la notación `@usuario` para que me notifique, pues solo incluir mi nombre de usuario no lo hace.

Comment: jachguate. Listo ya hice como lo dices, tiene razón, yo me entiendo mis garabatos, pero así como dices, queda para que las demás personas lo entiendan sin ningún problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener las *notas* de los períodos relevantes, puedes incluir varias veces más la tabla que tiene la información (`boletindetalle`), una vez por cada período que quieres reflejar.

Comento, de entrada, que he planteado así la solución porque he podido observar que hay una serie de información que incluyes en la vista actual que depende del período y para no cambiar completamente el enfoque con el que ya tienes funcionando las cosas.

Dicho esto, puedes *modificar* la vista actual, o quizás crear una nueva vista con 3 campos adicionales, uno para la nota de cada período, quitando el campo `BoDetNotaFinal`, que ya no tendría sentido. Para añadir cada uno de estos campos, he hecho un `left join` con la tabla `boletindetalle`, añadiendo a la condición los campos que he podido intuir que son necesarios para obtener la nota del mismo curso, para el mismo boletín, en los diferentes períodos, y he agregado la condición `bd2.BoDetPeriId <= BolDeta.BoDetPeriId` para que el boletín de un período no muestre las notas de períodos posteriores aunque ya se encuentren en la base de datos.

Las consulta para una vista, quedaría más o menos así:

```
SELECT   BolEnca.BoleId
       , BolEnca.BoleAnnoLectivo
       , BolDeta.BoDetId
       , BolEnca.BoleAlumDocumento AS Documento
       , concat_ws(' ', Alum.AlumApellido1, Alum.AlumApellido2, Alum.AlumNombre1, Alum.AlumNombre2 ) As "Alumno"
       , BolDeta.BoDetPeriId
       , Peri.PeriDetalle AS Período
       , BolEnca.BoleGradId
       , Grad.GradDetalle
       , BolEnca.BoleDoceDocumento
       , concat_ws(' ', Docent.DoceApellidos, Docent.DoceNombres) AS Docente
       , BolEnca.BoleObservaAluId
       , ObsAlum.ObAluObservaciones
       , BolEnca.BoleDirectorId
       , DireCol.DiCNombreComp
       , BolDeta.BoDetAreaId
       , BolDeta.BoDetOrdenArea
       , Area.AreaDetalle AS Área
       , BolDeta.BoDetMateId
       , Mate.MateDetalle AS Materia
       , BolDeta.BoDetIntensidad AS Intensidad
       , BolDeta.BoDetLogros
       , bd1.BoDetNotaFinal NotaPeriodo1
       , bd2.BoDetNotaFinal NotaPeriodo2
       , bd3.BoDetNotaFinal NotaPeriodo3
  FROM boletindetalle As BolDeta
       INNER JOIN boletinenca AS BolEnca ON BolDeta.BoDetBoDetId=BolEnca.BoleId
       INNER JOIN periodos AS Peri ON BolDeta.BoDetPeriId=Peri.PeriId
       INNER JOIN areas AS Area ON BolDeta.BoDetAreaId=Area.AreaId
       INNER JOIN materias AS Mate ON BolDeta.BoDetMateId=Mate.MateId
       INNER JOIN alumnos AS Alum ON BolEnca.BoleAlumDocumento=Alum.AlumDocumento
       INNER JOIN grados AS Grad ON BoleGradId=Grad.GradId
       INNER JOIN docentes As Docent ON BolEnca.BoleDoceDocumento=Docent.DoceDocumento
       INNER JOIN directorcol As DireCol ON BolEnca.BoleDirectorId=DireCol.DiCId
       INNER JOIN observacalumnos AS ObsAlum ON BolEnca.BoleObservaAluId=ObsAlum.ObAluId
       left join boletindetalle bd1 on bd1.BoDetBoDetId = BolDeta.BoDetBoDetId
                                   and bd1.BoDetAreaId = BolDeta.BoDetAreaId
                                   and bd1.BoDetMateId = BolDeta.BoDetMateId
                                   and bd1.BoDetPeriId <= BolDeta.BoDetPeriId
                                   and bd1.BoDetPeriId = 1
       left join boletindetalle bd2 on bd2.BoDetBoDetId = BolDeta.BoDetBoDetId
                                   and bd2.BoDetAreaId = BolDeta.BoDetAreaId
                                   and bd2.BoDetMateId = BolDeta.BoDetMateId
                                   and bd2.BoDetPeriId <= BolDeta.BoDetPeriId
                                   and bd2.BoDetPeriId = 2
       left join boletindetalle bd3 on bd3.BoDetBoDetId = BolDeta.BoDetBoDetId
                                   and bd3.BoDetAreaId = BolDeta.BoDetAreaId
                                   and bd3.BoDetMateId = BolDeta.BoDetMateId
                                   and bd3.BoDetPeriId <= BolDeta.BoDetPeriId
                                   and bd3.BoDetPeriId = 3
```

Y la consulta para traer un boletín específico sería muy similar a la que ya tienes, solo cuidando de incluir los nuevos campos:

```
SELECT        Alumno, BoDetAreaId, BoDetId, BoDetLogros, BoDetMateId, NotaPeriodo1, NotaPeriodo2, NotaPeriodo3, BoDetOrdenArea, BoDetPeriId, BoleAnnoLectivo, BoleDoceDocumento, BoleGradId, BoleId, BoleObservaAluId, BoleDirectorId, DiCNombreComp, 
                     Docente, Documento, GradDetalle, Intensidad, Materia, ObAluObservaciones, Período, Área
FROM            BoletinCompletoPeriodos
WHERE        (BoleAnnoLectivo = @RepParamAnno) AND (BoleGradId = @RepParamGrado) AND (BoDetPeriId = @RepParamPeriodo) AND (Documento = @RepParamDocuAlumno)
ORDER BY Documento, BoDetOrdenArea, BoDetMateId
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar jachguate, inicialmente tenia la vista con las 3 notas del periodo, es decir NotaPe1, NotaPe2 y NotaPe3, pero como la observaciones de los alumnos, los logros cambian y el número de periodo cambian, entonces lo hacia actualizando esos campos que deben cambiar, y pues no me parecía que quedaba bien y por eso cambien, para dejarlo solo con la nota de cada periodo. Hay ratos en que he contemplado volver a como lo tenia inicialmente.

Comment: Gracias, jachguate, ya estoy analizando su respuesta, ahora confirmo como me va.

Comment: La consulta cumple con lo requerido muchas gracias jachguate, se nota lo novato que soy, es que estoy con el proyecto de grado, para poderme graduar como ingeniero de sistemas. Nuevamente muchas gracias.